# webapi2 owin, I can't get a project started

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, iis-8

I'm struggling getting a project setup to host only web api an owin. The goal is to deploy to IIS.

I've tried the following: 
http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/07/06/building-a-web-api-2-project-from-scratch-using-owinkatana-net-part-2-owin-host/

In the end, I'm not finding things that work. Plus I'm not understanding what is actually needed. For example, I did much of the following on https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service

1. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
2. Created the StartUp.cs file
3. Added the assembly attribute pointing to the startup file within the startup file
4. Added the valuescontroller for a simple test.

I did not create APIServiceTest which is extended from ServiceBase.

The template for WebApi2 sucks. It always includes MVC. I'd just really like to understand what's need for owin and webapi 2.x

Can anyone help me or point me to something that works within visual studio 2015?

As always, thank you!
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this tutorial?

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

It´s very well explained I recently followed it and lead to absolute success.

Also, you can download its codebase here:

https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication

Comment: I appreciate the link @Luis-henrique-martins-lins-rol, but it still fails right when I delete the global config on step 4. Am I thinking of it correctly? I ran it via debugger (f5) before and it worked. When I excluded global.* files and did the same, the app then failed with cannot find the global.asax.cs.

Comment: It looks like me excluding it vs deleting it was the issue. Thanks for your help again @Luis!